# Sending info from database to SideNavigation blade through BaseController is good?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have Layout Page that has following blade references.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @include('Includes.head')                    //reference - 1
</head>
<body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
        <div class="main_container">
            @include('Includes.topheader')       //reference - 2
            @include('Includes.sideNavigations') //reference - 3
            @yield('content')
            @include('Includes.footer')          //reference - 4
        </div>
    </div>
    @include('Includes.footerscripts')           //reference - 5
</body>
</html>
```

I want to send list of record to Side navigation. Can somebody suggest if I should use Base Controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would use `app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php` and perform the query in the constructor, then pass it to the view with `view()->share()`

Make sure to cache the results too so that it isn't querying on every request.